# Image Matching to solve captcha

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, similarity, image-recognition

I am building a bot with python and I need some system to solve captchas like these:

[image: captcha]

I think I need a deep learning algorithm, but coding one is a pain in the ass. Is there any easy solution to this?

I can code the part that screenshots the images and clicks on the correct answer, image 4 or 5 in the example. The images get rotated and change every time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple yet effective solution without using the deep learning algorithm.

Divide the problem into 2 parts:

1. Segmentation: You'll need to do some image processing like edge detection and segment all the objects in the given captcha and save the region of interest (OpenCV can help). Assign labels to the objects.
2. Similarity Measurement: Use some scale and rotational invariant feature descriptor algorithm to extract features from the objects, and a matcher to compare the objects for a similarity measure (check SIFT/SURF features).

Based on the similarity scores, make a decision.